# Continuity/Differentiability of Fourier Series

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Possibly stupid question:

I'm wondering if there is some trick for evaluating the continuity/differentiability of a Fourier series. In particular, I'm looking at the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} e^{inx}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Think about a relevant geometric series. Or about the M-test, or about comparison to a known series.

Comment: Evaluating the geometric series certainly works. I guess I was wondering if there was any if there was a general way of approaching the problem, perhaps without evaluating the sum. Probably not. Thanks though.

Comment: @Faust : I'm guessing there is a huge literature on this question and many conditions known under which the sum is continuous and/or differentiable.